# c#: Writing a test for this use case

Tags: unit-testing, c#-3.0, nunit, moq

I want to check if the users password has been changed, what is the best way to write this test? Is my code in need of refactoring because it is wrong?

Inside the code password.ResetUserPassword - I find out which user is requesting a password change, if they can change, and generating an email if needs to be... Do I need to pass in a `User` objects to this method? This logic is called by my controller (or backend if needs to be)

```
    [Test]
    public void Test_If_New_Password_Is_Generated_For_User()
    {
        var repo = new ReadOnlySession();
        var update = new UpdateSession();

        var passwordService = new UserPasswordService();
        var password = new AccountProfileProcessor(repo, update, passwordService);

        password.ResetUserPassword("companyid", "jon.smithers", null);

        Assert.Pass();

    }
```

//The method that I am calling

_`passwordService` is a service that handles generating a new key for the user

```
    public void ResetUserPassword(string identifier, string loginid, string passwordreseturl)
    {
        //get user object
        var currentUser = _readOnlySession.All<User>()
            .Where(x => x.Login == loginid)
            .SingleOrDefault(); //any other logic to get user resides here...

        if (currentUser == null)
            throw new UserNotFoundException();

        _passwordService.ResetPassword(currentUser.User, identifier, loginid);

        //persist data
        _updateSession.Update(currentUser.User);

        //send out email with the url as a link inside the email
    }
```

Comment: How to request current password? I mean before and after the change?

Comment: Basically I want to get the users profile check credentials, make the call, then check if the data has changed. Is that a valid test? Would I need to refactor this? Kinda 2 questions: is my unit test valid? If not, is it because my code needs refactoring...

Comment: It seems valid but I need more details regarding `check if data has changed`, how to do this? How you can check a value of new password?

Comment: @sll- lol, thats where I am stumbling on, basically a record (PasswordKey) is it different from the original key, that is all my test.

Comment: I believe you can inject mock of the _passwordService and intercept `ResetPassword()` call paremeters but I'm not sure whether it is enough, I'm not familar with your classes logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following would work. (I had to make a few assumptions about your classes, and I'm still not sure what type currentUser.User is.)

The trick with mocking and decoupling is to make all of your service dependencies interfaces.

You'll need another interface dependency (with associated mock and verification) for the mail sending. You might want to put all of these in a separate test fixture, arrange in setup, then verify each service call in a separate test method.

To me this method is doing too much - it has multiple responsibilities. The painful test setup and multiple verifications are code smells. Consider breaking it into smaller methods (probably still called from the existing method) and then testing those independently. `GetUser(loginId)` (or throw) would be the first method I'd extract. Moving some of these methods onto the services (such as the repository) would make this easier to test.

**Clarification** - You mention in the comments that you want to check if the PasswordKey is different. That's the responsibility of the concrete `UserPasswordService`. You'll need to test that independently.

```
// Arrange

const string TestLogin = "jon.smithers";
User testUser = new User { Login = TestLogin };
var testUsers = new List<User> { testUser };

var mockUpdate = new Mock<IUpdateSession>();

var mockRepo = new Mock<IReadOnlySession>();
mockRepo.Setup(x => x.All<User>()).Returns(testUsers);

var mockPasswordService = new Mock<IUserPasswordService>();

var password = new AccountProfileProcessor(
    mockRepo.Object, mockUpdate.Object, mockPasswordService.Object);

// Act

password.ResetUserPassword("companyid", TestLogin, null);

// Assert

mockPasswordService.Verify(
    x => x.ResetPassword(
        It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), TestLogin));

mockUpdate.Verify(x => x.Update(testUser));
```

Comment: currentUser is a User (LinqToSql) object, the problem with database calls is, you cannot really extract them out, annonymous types are difficult to work with, In this scenario above I removed the various joins onto other tables (User Profile and company), I think what I hear from you is what I decided to do, test each service individually, Yes I do have the EmailService which I call via an interface. My requirements are - change password, then send out an email. I am keeping all my services as simple as possible - that is one thing I do not want to complicate, it is far easier to test also.

Comment: I'd recommend against exposing IQueryable from your repository. There is some debate over this; here's an article that matches my views: http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/05/11/iqueryable-can-kill-your-dog-steal-your-wife-kill-your-will-to-live-etc/

Comment: If I dont expose IQueryable then I have no chance of doing all the complex joins, that would mean I have to make up all sorts of repositories to get my stuff working. I would rather call my db as I wish, when I wish, all params differ, sometimes I need something for my view, other times I dont, I am tied to a straight jacket otherwise, trust me. :)